# Get the list of subscriptions subscribed under a topic in AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

How do I get the list of subscriptions subscribed under a topic in AWS Java SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an [AmazonSNSClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html) and then invoke [listSubscriptionsByTopic()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html#listSubscriptionsByTopic-com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.ListSubscriptionsByTopicRequest-) on it.